# modal box preview and next with close and click preview and next button changes content with responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5lJj.png)

Hello,

I have attached above image i want to modal box preview and next with close and click preview and next button changes content, images with responsive any one help me.

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried. That will be helpful

Comment: Have you done any code please share it.

Comment: I have only html pages don't have code  so you have providing me any reference example